# Unpack data in python from C++

Tags: python, c++, byte

**Problem**

I need to send 2 float from C++ to python, and vice-versa. 
I am using the C++ library `winsock2.h`, and the function `send()` that requires the buffer to be `char*`. 
I want to send, for example  this string to python:

```
std::string string = "1 12.3"
```

**My try**

When using `struct.unpack("..")` python returns the wrong numbers. 
I tried with many different values inside the string in unpack, but it never works. 
 
How should I structure my unpack to work correctly? Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you're unpacking and what you get and the exact syntax of your `struct.unpack("...")`?

Comment: A lot depends on how you send that `string`. If you `send(sock, &string, string.length(), 0);` You literally sent the `string` object (and probably too much or too little of it) rather than the data pointed at by the `string`. The receiver will get a useless pointer to memory that's invalid in a different process and some bookkeeping variables. You'll need to read up on serialization.

Comment: @user4581301 I am sending the string (since it's a char*), but the size of the string is always 24 bytes and it does not depend on the values inside. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll read on serialization

Comment: There we go. `std::string` is not a `char*`. It is a container for a `char*` bundled together with some book-keeping variables (and these days a small buffer for short strings so it can avoid dynamic allocations). The size of a datatype is always the same no matter how much stuff it might be pointing at because the size ids determined by the size of the pointer, not the object pointed at. That constant size is one of the things that makes arrays possible.

Comment: You could `send(sock, string.c_str(), string.length(), 0);`, but this doesn't include any information to the receiver about the length of the string, making it impossible to unpack: the reader doesn't know how much data to read. In modern C++ you can `send(sock, string.c_str(), string.length()+1, 0);` to send the null terminator, but then the reader has to play getta-byte getta-byte getta-byte-byte-byte  looking for the null.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the clarification on the string. Yes, I am actually sending `send(sock, string.c_string(), sizeof(string),0);`, but the main problem is that I don't know what to put inside `struct.unpack(..)` to recognize 2 different float.

Comment: I suggest an alternative: Establish a communications protocol. When you send data over a wire all sorts of things can go wrong when you send data structures. They system byte orders (endian) can be different. The size if data types can be different. The structure packing and padding rules can be different. It almost never works. But if you've defined your own rules and follow those rules, anything that goes wrong is your fault and you can fix it. Also, if you're using it, keep in mind that TCP is a stream protocol. It doesn't respect your message boundaries at all.

Comment: This is what the `format` argument of `struct.unpack(format, buffer)` is doing, describing the protocol. I'm not a Python programmer so I don't know how well it handles the extra surprises of a C++ structure, but I suspect it's up to you to specify reading extra bytes etc... to handle padding. And this will frequently fail after recompiling the C++ code with different options or a change in compilers or new hardware. Establish a protocol at both ends and YOU are in CONTROL!  Muhuahahahahaha!

Comment: @user4581301 I am not entirely sure what you mean with creating my own protocol. It's something I have never done. I just need to send a few bytes from C++ to python and vice-versa, and doing it with a shared database is incredibly slow.

Comment: Is the string you want to send actually a string, constructed via something like `sprintf`, or just two floats copied into a byte array? `struct.unpack` is useful for converting raw bytes, not human readable strings, and as such will throw an exception if you pass it an unexpected number of bytes.